# Get list of keys from a dictionary matches to list of values

Tags: python-3.x

```
dictionary = {"raj": 2, "striver": 3, "vikram": 4}
myvals = [2,4]
```

Need to get ['raj', 'vikram'] as a list filtering above dictionary using myvals list

tried

```
result = [dictionary[k] for k in [2, 4]]
result = [dictionary[k] for k in myvals]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[k for k, v in dictionary.items() if v in myvals]
```